# GroupBy in Pandas without using Aggregate Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a retail datastore and trying to get a report of category and sub-category. I tried looking at the stackoverflow answers but I was not able to find the solution.

Below is the sample data (not the complete dataset)

```
+-----------------+--------------+
|    Category     | Sub-Category |
+-----------------+--------------+
| Furniture       | Bookcases    |
| Furniture       | Chairs       |
| Office Supplies | Labels       |
| Furniture       | Tables       |
| Office Supplies | Storage      |
| Furniture       | Furnishings  |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

My code:

```
orders[['Category', 'Sub-Category']].groupby(by=['Category', 'Sub-Category']).nunique()
```

My result Set:

```
                              Category  Sub-Category
Category        Sub-Category                        
Furniture       Bookcases            1             1
                Chairs               1             1
                Furnishings          1             1
                Tables               1             1
Office Supplies Appliances           1             1
                Art                  1             1
```

All I want is

```
    Category        Sub-Category                        

    Furniture       Bookcases       
                    Chairs            
                    Furnishings  
                    Tables    
    Office Supplies Appliances       
                    Art
```

Is there a way that I can hide the counts. If I don't include the `nunique` then I am returned the object instead of the actual output.

I am not sure if this functionality exists in pandas or should I look at something else.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
df=df.sort_values('Category')
df.Category=df.Category.mask(df.Category.duplicated(),'')
df
Out[450]: 
         Category Sub-Category
0       Furniture    Bookcases
1                       Chairs
3                       Tables
5                  Furnishings
2  OfficeSupplies       Labels
4                      Storage
```

Comment: This is the error AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method. I am using pycharm.

Comment: @Ravi do not using groupby

Comment: @Ravi use this in the original df without the groupby. should work

Comment: @W-B this is getting me all the non-unique values. There are millions of records in the file and I need to have unique values. The dataset I provided was for reference. It has many more values.

Comment: I think you just to added `df = df.sort_values(['Category','Sub-Category']).drop_duplicates()` before the first statement in @W-B solution.

Comment: @Ravi please follow Scott's recommendation